# Session getting destroy if java web application deployed Websphere 6.1

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, websphere

Please help me for below issue,

I am working in Upgrade project. WAS server getting upgrade to Websphere 6.1, Java J2EE application we compiled with IBM JDK1.5.

Now we hosted J2EE application in newly installed WAS 6.1. Client application sending Login request and getting login successfully. If client send next request the session is getting destroyed some session values, So I am getting Null pointer exception.

Can any one say, Is there any settings we need to do in websphere server, or we need to do something in application side.

But it is working fine in TOMCAT server

Comment: Maybe the application needs to have its own JSESSIONID. There are some steps to get this done, but first you should do some debug. With Chrome browser, see the JSESSIONID of your app at the first request. Then see if the second request change the value of the JSESSIONID

Comment: WAS 6.1 is extremely old and out of support. I'd suggest using 8.5.5 instead if you are doing upgrade anyway. Going back to your question, do you have security enabled, what kind of authentication are you using,(provided by container or custom)?

Comment: Hi I am using custom, Manually checking by java code

Comment: Hi edubriguenti Can you please tell me how to get its own JSESSIONID.

Comment: Do you have many different servers on that host, or applications? Is it possible that they are overwriting session cookie for each other? Session is either present or fully destroyed, `some session values are null` is not possible. Add code where you are creating session and doing login.

Comment: Guys
Sorry for too late reply. This issue has been solved, as the issue was in MQ side due to some reason the MQ was destroyed the session so it was created new session. So issue is been solved in MQ side. now it working fine.

Thanks for all